# How to open an Electron dialog from angular 2 component?

Tags: angular, electron

I want to click a button to open folder dialog in my component. Here is what I am trying to do:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input class="u-full-width" placeholder="Folder" type="text" [(ngModel)]="folder">
    <button id="browse" class="button-primary" (click)="browse()">Browse</button>
    <input id="fileInput" type="file" style="display: none" />
</div>
```

component.ts

```
// var remote = require('remote');
// var dialog = remote.require('dialog');

  folder: string;
  browse() {
    dialog.showOpenDialog({title: 'Select a folder', properties: ['openDirectory']}, (folderPath) => {
        if (folderPath === undefined){
            console.log("You didn't select a folder");
            return;
        }
        this.folder = folderPath;
    });
  }
```

So, how do I import remote and dialog?

Answer (score 7):

Just import the "remote" module using es6 import,and then your ts file will be like

```
import { remote } from 'electron';

folder: string;
browse() {
    remote.dialog.showOpenDialog({title: 'Select a folder', properties: ['openDirectory']}, (folderPath) => {
        if (folderPath === undefined){
            console.log("You didn't select a folder");
            return;
        }
        this.folder = folderPath;
    });
  }
```

Comment: This helped me. Thanks.

Comment: @Gurjeetsingh if this answer helped you, [mark it as 'correct' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 2):

You can try it with the `ngx-electron` library

```
import {ElectronService} from 'ngx-electron'

export class DialogHelper {

    private static alert = new ElectronService().remote.dialog;
}
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer, although @shobhit-sharma could use DI instead of  calling new

Comment: As much as this is right, It is good practice to give a complete response to the answer without making assumptions... i.e how one may use your solution.

Comment: @Alex, yes you can do by DI

Comment: I am trying to use this and the ElctronService.remote is undefined, does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

You're close. According to the documentation (https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/dialog.md) to use it in the renderer you need to do `const {dialog} = require('electron').remote` so your first `remote` variable isn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, when I try this code, I got error in browser console as `Uncaught TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function     at Object.<anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:72631)...`, and the app just shows "Loading..."

Comment: I see. In your main process when you are creating the window are you disabling node integration? If so then you may need to put the code above in to a preload script. See this conversation for further details https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5113

Comment: Actually, I switched to another sample code base from [https://github.com/onehungrymind/electrogram](https://github.com/onehungrymind/electrogram), which has code to open the dialog. Thank you very much!