# How to pick folder path using Angular 6

Tags: html, angular6

I'm trying to pick the folder path string. I'm not trying to upload anything, just be able to trap the path.
using this always try to open a file:

```
<input id="folder-input" #folderRef type="file" directory />
```

With the accompanying risk, this is not possible, is it!?

Comment: I am on the same way :-( ... I tried ngx-file-helpers (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-file-helpers) it has not worked , but I posted an issue.

Comment: we should probably chip in 50 points each for a bounty, will you match my 50 points if I start one?

Comment: I don't know how really this works , sharing etc ... but YES , go. However , I found this https://github.com/statictypeme/ng-file-manager or https://github.com/statictypeme/ng-file-manager-express. It is not very clear at the moment in my mind  , but it seems behave like a proxy you can use over rest api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, if you package electron with your angular app.
electron is targeting and packaging chrome web browsser.

[How to open an Electron dialog from angular 2 component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43398999/how-to-open-an-electron-dialog-from-angular-2-component)

references :
https://jaketrent.com/post/select-directory-in-electron/
https://alligator.io/angular/electron/

Comment: I'll check little later. Why many were saying that it is impossible for the security reason that user's filesystem is not supposed to be available for javascript?

Comment: for safety reasons , most of the browser does not allow it anymore. using electron permits it, since it targets only chrome browser api. (Note: VScode is electron based..)